# How can I preselect a radio button using javascript or jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know this is probably easy, but I just can't figure it out.

I am working with a SAAS shopping cart solution so I can't adjust the form code or use PHP, so I need to use javascript or jquery.

In this cart, I have a form....

```
<form method="post" action="cart.php" id="productDetailsAddToCartForm">  
Please Select a Bottle Size:  
<ul>  
<li><label><input name="variation[1]" type="radio" class="RadioButton" value="30"  /> 11oz</label></li> 
<li><label><input name="variation[1]" type="radio" class="RadioButton" value="31"  /> 33oz </label>  
</li>  
</ul>  
</form>
```

And I need to preselect the first radio button using jquery or javascript.

Can you help?

Comment: If you want to preselect why you want it from jquery or javascript you can do it from simple html
 `<input type=radio value='11oz'  name='name' checked='checked' />`

Comment: @skankhan: "so I can't adjust the form code or use PHP"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [`attr`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) method with `checked` like this:

```
$('.RadioButton:first').attr('checked', true);
```

Or

```
$('.RadioButton:first').attr('checked', 'checked');
```

Note that `:first` will select the first radio button there.

Comment: Actually, it now checks it but the form still says please make a selection.  It's like it marks it, but doesn't register it.  Is there another way?  Thanks

Comment: @Ray Walker: If the radio is checked, your problem is solved. If there is another issue, you should ask another question explaining your problem :)

Answer (score 6):

```
$(':input:radio:eq(0)').attr('checked', 'checked');
```

This will check the first radio box on the page.

Comment: Actually, it now checks it but the form still says please make a selection. It's like it marks it, but doesn't register it. Is there another way? Thanks

Comment: @Ray: The box is checked, there may be an issue elsewhere in your code.